# Two pipelines for single filebeat input | ELK version (6.5.4)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I am trying to create multiple pipelines first-pipeline and second-pipeline in logstash listening to beats events from the same port but getting an error saying the address in use for the second pipeline and the reason why I am using two pipelines is that I want *pipeline.workers: 1* only for selected indexes in which sequence of log matters.
ERROR:

```
Pipeline_id:second-pipeline

Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Beats host=>"127.0.0.1", port=>5044, 
id=>"7c07a66c7959c1734f6aead8ca456bc7c3b086aafb7b5bd4882ee45e0f3c9fc5", 
enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_4d22b75f-e478-4fbc- 
b5fe-27ae02ac486b", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, ssl=>false, 
add_hostname=>true, ssl_verify_mode=>"none", ssl_peer_metadata=>false, 
include_codec_tag=>true, ssl_handshake_timeout=>10000, tls_min_version=>1, 
tls_max_version=>1.2, cipher_suites=>["TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", 
"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", 
"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384", 
"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", 
"TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"], client_inactivity_timeout=>60, 
executor_threads=>8>
Error: Address already in use
Exception: Java::JavaNet::BindException
    Stack: sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(sun/nio/ch/Net.java:438)
 sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(sun/nio/ch/Net.java:430)
 sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(sun/nio/ch/ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:225)
```

**pipelines.yml**

```
- pipeline.id: first-pipeline
      path.config: "/Users/gyrao/Documents/ELK/logstash-6.5.4/config/pipelines/api-address.config"
      pipeline.batch.size: 1

- pipeline.id: second-pipeline
      path.config: "/Users/gyrao/Documents/ELK/logstash-6.5.4/config/pipelines/my-config.config"
      pipeline.workers: 1
      pipeline.batch.size: 1
      queue.type: persisted
      path.queue: "/Users/gyrao/Documents/ELK/logstash-6.5.4/config/queue"
```

**my-config.config**

```
input {
    beats {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => 5044
    }
}
filter {

}
output {

}
```

**api-address.config**

```
input {
    beats {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => 5044
    }
}
filter {

}
output {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have two inputs with the same port, but you can use a distributor pattern to receive everything in one input, and then sending to a different pipeline with the configuration you need.

So you can have:

master-pipeline

```
input {
    beats {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => 5044
    }
}
filter {
}
output {
    if([someField] === "some_value") {
        pipeline {
            send_to => first_pipeline
        }
    }
    else {
        pipeline {
            send_to => second_pipeline
        }
    }

}
```

Then individual pipelines should look like this:

```
input {
    pipeline {
        address => first_pipeline
    }
}

...
```

And your pipelines file:

```
- pipeline.id: master-pipeline
      path.config: "/Users/gyrao/Documents/ELK/logstash-6.5.4/config/pipelines/master-pipeline.config"
      pipeline.batch.size: 1
- pipeline.id: first-pipeline
      path.config: "/Users/gyrao/Documents/ELK/logstash-6.5.4/config/pipelines/api-address.config"
      pipeline.batch.size: 1
- pipeline.id: second-pipeline
      path.config: "/Users/gyrao/Documents/ELK/logstash-6.5.4/config/pipelines/my-config.config"
      pipeline.workers: 1
      pipeline.batch.size: 1
      queue.type: persisted
      path.queue: "/Users/gyrao/Documents/ELK/logstash-6.5.4/config/queue"
```

Read more here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html#distributor-pattern

Comment: One notice here regarding batch.size = 1, it's necessary because of your requirement, but it can considerably reduce the throughput of your pipeline.